# How to convert a String to all spaces in Bash?

Tags: string, bash, unix, replace

For formatting purposes, I want to replace all characters of a String with spaces.

```
STR="some string of unknown length"
SPC="                             " <--- this is what I want
```

With help of [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), the best I could come up with is this:

```
SPC=${STR//[a-Z]/ }
```

But this only replaces letters, not digits or any special characters. What's the placeholder for "any character" with this type of Bash string replacements?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you want to do this _for formatting purposes,_ since for most formatting purposes you can use `printf`. For example, `str="some string of unknown length"; printf '%*s|%s\n%s|%s\n' "${#str}" "" "hello" "$str" "goodbye"`.

Comment: Good point. I simply wasn't aware of that... too stuck on `echo` rather than using `printf`. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
str="some string of unknown length"
spc="${str//[^[:space:]]/ }"
```

`[^[:space:]]` will match any non-space character and replace it by space.

Verify:

```
echo "$str" | wc -c
30
echo "$spc" | wc -c
30
```

PS: You can also do:

```
spc="${str//?/ }"
```

to get the string of same length containing only spaces. `?` matches any character in glob.

Comment: Why bother matching non-space characters? Converting a space to a space may be pointless, but it reads better than a regex.

Comment: Thanks for that question mark! I tried with a dot and a star... ;-)

Comment: @anubhava: i don't know why but your solution in my environment (GNU bash, versione 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
) does not work...

Comment: Not sure why as `"${str//?/ }"` works for me on all the BASH versions I tried. It even worked on older BASH 3.2 on OSX

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative (no regex/parsing at all) solution:

```
STR='some string of unknown length.' # Actually 30 chars
# Create an SCP var of the same length of STR filled with spaces (# updated implementation, thanks gniourf_gniourf)
printf -v SCP '%*s' ${#STR}
```

**Test**:

```
echo "${STR}"                 # 'some string of unknown length.'
echo "${SCP}"                 # '                              '
echo "Length STR -> ${#STR}"  # 'Length STR -> 30'
echo "Length SCP -> ${#SCP}"  # 'Length SCP -> 30'
```

**How it works**:

The `printf` command writes in variable `SCP` a string of at least the length equal to the number of chars of `STR` (`${#STR}`).

The tricks is in the `s` not replaced cause there is no further parameter after `${#STR}`.

**Usage example**:

```
printf '%*s' 3       # '   '
printf '%*s' 3 .     # '  .'
printf '%*s' 3 123   # '123'
printf '%*s' 3 12345 # '12345'
```

Comment: Rather: `printf -v scp '%*s' "${#str}"`: no subshells and no external tools.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but this is also POSIX-compliant (well, a variant, anyway, at the expense of a single subshell: `SPC=$(printf %${#STR}s)`.